# Can not break Tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I have used `tcolorbox` as an item to highlight some content. It works fine in general. However, when the box gets big, instead of breaking between the pages, it simply moves to the new page. This creates whitespace problem for me. How do I solve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\begin{document}
%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \lipsum[1-2]
        \item[\textcolor{DarkGreen}{\textbullet}]
            \leavevmode
            \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.934\textwidth,colback={white},title={Title},colbacktitle={DarkGreen},coltitle=white,colframe={DarkGreen}]
            \parskip=5pt
                \lipsum[3-5]
            \end{tcolorbox}
            }
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colorbox needs the `breakable` option and may not be hidden in unbreakable elements like the `adjustbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
\lipsum[1-2]
    \item[\textcolor{DarkGreen}{\textbullet}]
    \leavevmode
    \vspace*{-1.7em}
%    \adjustbox{valign=t}{%
         \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.934\textwidth,colback={white},title={Title},colbacktitle={DarkGreen},coltitle=white,colframe={DarkGreen},breakable]
         \parskip=5pt

          \lipsum[3-5]
          \end{tcolorbox}
%          }
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Also, how do I make the box look more like a continued block? I would rather forego of the bottom line of the box on the first page and top line of the box on the second page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @g_vasare This sounds like a new question. Can you please open a new post about this? Not many people will see it in a comment

Comment: @g_vasare Add option `enhanced` to the box and bottom/top lines on break will disappear